# is there a way of joining two tables with the clause, "inner join," then followed by multiple "left join" clause

Tags: php, mysql

i'm setting up mysql query against four table, i want the result of the left not to have effect on the query of the inner join. what am i do wrong? forgive my naivety

the problem here is that when i remove the two left join in the query i get eight results as expected but with the left join in the query i get only one result even when there're more products in the product table.

```
$this->getAllRecords("SELECT t.content_type_name as type, 
                        p.title,p.start_date, p.end_date, p.last_enroll_date, 
                        p.seat, p.cost, p.description, COUNT(r.stars) as review_count, 
                        AVG(r.stars) as stars, i.image, p.location 
                    FROM content_type t 
                        INNER JOIN product p ON t.content_type_id=c.content_type_id 
                        LEFT JOIN product_review r ON p.product_id=r.product_id 
                        LEFT JOIN image i ON p.uid=i.reference_page_or_product 
                            AND p.active=1 
                    ORDER BY RAND() 
                    LIMIT 8"))
```

i want all product whether there are reviews and image or not

Comment: Have you run the full query directly against your database to confirm that something in your code isn't filtering out the desired rows?

Comment: seems weird  that with the left join you get less rows ... show the code without left  join  ...

Comment: Could you please show us an example for this problem as you can see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=209d42f6a535d4921defdde140336bf4    This usually isn't the matter

Comment: I'm really sorry for coming to party late. @Patrick Q i have run the query against the database but i have no idea what's filtering the result. Just like as i mention earlier the query works properly once i take off the two left join clause.

Comment: @scaisEdge here is the code without the left join and it worked as expected ``` $this->getAllRecords("SELECT t.content_type_name as type, p.title, p.start_date, p.end_date, p.last_enroll_date, p.seat, p.cost, p.description, p.location FROM content_type t INNER JOIN product p ON t.content_type_id=c.content_type_id AND p.active=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8"))```

Comment: @Tetranyble  i have posted an answer  hope is useful

Comment: @scaisEdge i have seen your answer and am tinkering with it right now. i shall give feedback in no time. I'm really sorry for yesterday for keeping everyone waiting. we closed early yesterday. i appreciate your effort Sir. thank you so much

Comment: @Tetranyble  no problem  ..  on the internet, there is no space and no time, everything happens where and when it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using aggreation function withou group by  and this could produce unpredictable result  (probaly you are using a mysql db version preceding 5.7)

The aggredated  result could be related  to null value and this also can reduce/omit the result

You should  use  group by for aggreation function and use a subquery for obtain the related  valid result  ..  and use the subqiery for left join

```
SELECT t.content_type_name as type
      , p.title,p.start_date
      , p.end_date
      , p.last_enroll_date
      , p.seat
      , p.cost
      , p.description
      , p.location 
      , i.image
      , t.review_count
      , t.stars
FROM content_type t 
INNER JOIN product p ON t.content_type_id=c.content_type_id 
    AND p.active=1 
LEFT JOIN  (
  SELECT r.product_id
          , COUNT(r.stars) as review_count
          , AVG(r.stars) as stars
  FROM product_review r
  GROUP BY r.product_id
) t ON ON p.product_id=t.product_id 
LEFT JOIN image i ON p.uid=i.reference_page_or_product 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 8
```

For better view The p.active=1  should be assigned  to the on clause  for product

Answer (score -1):

See this page for proper nesting of joins, and use of parathesis: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/nested-join-optimization.html

but there is a bug in the SQL, which should be expressed as WHERE:

```
SELECT t.content_type_name as type, p.title,p.start_date, p.end_date, p.last_enroll_date, 
        p.seat, p.cost, p.description, COUNT(r.stars) as review_count, 
        AVG(r.stars) as stars, i.image, p.location 
  FROM content_type t 
       INNER JOIN product p ON t.content_type_id=c.content_type_id 
             LEFT JOIN product_review r ON p.product_id=r.product_id 
             LEFT JOIN image i ON p.uid=i.reference_page_or_product
```

> AND p.active=1

```
  ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: The link included DOES address the question in the heading... clearly showing that it is POSSIBLE.

The included quote shows a bug in his example code.

Comment: Well you should provide a fix for the bug, if you want to earn your upvotes.

Comment: @Berge  There is nothing inherently wrong with an `AND` clause in a `JOIN` condition.  While it is not exactly clear which rows the OP wants, putting that condition on the main query and not on the `JOIN` would actually potentially result in _fewer_ rows, not _more_.

Comment: @PatrickQ It is in the wrong place: either it should be added to the inner join or added in a where clause.

Comment: @Adder  As my comment indicated, that just depends on which rows OP wants, which remains unclear.  As written in the question, OP will only get image data for the cases where the product is active (but will still get product data).  There is nothing _wrong_ with that.  Putting that condition anywhere else will only result in fewer result rows, as all matches will be _required_ to meet that condition.  By putting in on the `image` join, rows not meeting that condition will still be returned, just without image data.  OP wants _more_ result rows, not _less_.

Comment: @Berge thanks for that link you shared it's helpful